# Проблема с composer и модулями phar и json

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer

Ребята, нервы дико сдают.
Устанавливаю на сервер ubuntu 18 PHPWord.

Понадобился composer.
Установил.
Пытаюсь запустить - они пишет:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The json extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-json

The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar

The iconv OR mbstring extension is required and both are missing.
Install either of them or recompile php without --disable-iconv
```

Пытаюсь установить phar - вот результат
sudo apt-get install php7.3-phar

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php7.3-common' instead of 'php7.3-phar'
php7.3-common is already the newest version (7.3.2-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

Не понимаю, почему он все время берет php7.3-common вместо php7.3-phar

Answer (score 1):

php7.3-phar является частью пакета php7.3-common. Поэтому он у вас уже установлен.

Проверить статус модуля:

```
phpquery -v7.3 -s SAPI -m MODULE
```

Активировать:

```
sudo phpenmod -v7.3 -s SAPI -m MODULE
```

Где

**SAPI** : (cli | fpm | apache2 )

**MODULE** : название модуля(без префикса php_)

## Ваши действия для устранения причин, указанных в сообщениях от Composer'a:

1. Установить json & iconv & mbstring

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.3-json php7.3-mbstring
```

2. Активировать модули:

```
sudo phpenmod -v7.3 -s cli -m phar json iconv mbstring
```